# How do I maintain manager at level 2 when no employees (level 1) assigned?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables to use for employee manager relationship. One table is employee id, and the other is the parent child link. I am joining the employee table multiple times along with the parent child link table, trying to create: Sr Mgr (Lvl 1), Mgr (Lvl 2), and Employee (Lvl 3) however I am running into an issue with Mgr who don't have employees assigned to them. There isnt a destination record with the mgrid as source.

**How would I go about creating a null record and keeping the mgr at level 2 who doesnt have employeeid assigned to them?**

***Table Layout***

EmpID table as Eid

| EmpID |
| --- |
| 123 |
| 456 |

ParentChild Table as PC:

| DestinationID (Child) | SourceID (Parent) |
| --- | --- |
| 456 | 123 |
| 789 | 123 |
| 111 | 789 |

**Joins**

```
Select eid.empID (Level_3), pc.sourceid (level_2), pc2.sourceid (level_1)
   From empid as eid
    Left join parentchild as pc on eid.empID = pc.destinationID
     Left Join empid as eid2 on pc.sourceId = eid2.empid
      Left join parentchild as pc2 on eid2.empid = pc2.destinationID
```

Expected results:

| Level_1 | Level_2 | Level_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Null | 456 | 123 |
| 111 | 789 | 123 |

The manager without employees only shows up at level 1 since they report to sr manager and not at level 2 with a level 1 null record.

| Level_1 | Level_2 | Level_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 456 | 123 | Null |
| 111 | 789 | 123 |

Comment: Could you share your expected result based on two tables?

Comment: Updated with expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With oracle (like Oracle 19c, etc) you'll need to make a few adjustments to your SQL syntax.  We only needed to use the linkage table `parentchild` to obtain the detail you required.

Try this one:

```
SELECT pc2.destinationid level_1, pc.destinationid level_2, pc.sourceid Level_3
  FROM      parentchild   pc
  LEFT JOIN parentchild   pc2   on pc2.sourceid  = pc.destinationid
 WHERE pc.sourceid = 123
;
```

Result:

```
+------+-----------+
|    1 |   2 |   3 |
+------+-----------+
|  111 | 789 | 123 |
| null | 456 | 123 |
+------+-----------+
```

[Full working test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e2f0ac8f7ba79c7eab7e96f31744ce27)

Note: With recursion, we don't need to use explicit joins for each level of the tree and the depth doesn't need to be known.  Oracle has two ways to do that:

1. `WITH clause` - Common Table Expression
2. `CONNECT BY`  - Oracle specific syntax